# saving url in a session for recently viewed webpages

Tags: php, session

i want to create a way to save the urls of recently viewed web pages in a session so when a user uses my site they can go on their account to see what they have looked at
so far i have this

```
<?php
session_start();
$currentpageurl = $_GET['username'];
$_SESSION['pageurl'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

foreach($_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

the problem is it just keeps going and doesn't stop when i need it to stop at the 10th last viewed pages and remove the oldest one when a new page is viewed

Comment: Where did you build in your "stop"? I dont see it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_shift to remove the latest value if your array becomes longer than 10.

```
<?php
session_start();
$currentpageurl = $_GET['username'];
$_SESSION['pageurl'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if( count( $_SESSION['pageurl'] ) > 10 ){
   array_shift( $_SESSION['pageurl'] );
}

foreach( $_SESSION['pageurl'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: hey just tried your code and i got this error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\garry.php on line 10

Comment: okay the code works up untill i reach 10 urls then i get the error: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\garry.php on line 11